I'm a little embarrassed by the research of one of my recommenders
Staying vague for the sake of anonymity.
I am applying for jobs and PhDs post-masters and I am in a bit of a dilemma.
Basically, I worked very closely with a professor over the last year who I am confident will say very positive things about me on an application, but whose research I am worried will make potential hiring committees a little cautious. The jobs I am applying for are in 'hard-nosed' empirical policy fields whereas this professor has a very strong 'leftist/postmodernist' emphasis.
I chose to keep working with them because they are very kind, the job was on a well regarded research program, there were limited RA positions at my university and it paid well. The wider area of the research is very topical in the current academic/political landscape and I found learning about it to be really interesting. I think I was able to own the parts of the research I had control over, learn the topics and the academic landscape well and I generally feel proud of this work, however I was never quite intellectually invested in many parts of the research which I ultimately found to be kind of 'light-weight'. I also didn't want to push back on the professor out of deference for their authority.
In my apps, I've been able to 'spin' my descriptions of the work by focussing on my specific contributions which are in line with the kinds of jobs I am applying for, but I am worried that listing this professor as a reference won't 'read' well and might undermine the real experience I think I have gained. On the other hand, this is a large and recent part of my resume and touches on an area that many employers are interested in. The professor is really pleased with my work so I know I will get a good rec.
I am interested in what y'all have to say about this. How likely is it that potential employers will be thrown off if I list them?

Although the answers you've received here are sensible, this sort of thing can vary a lot by field and industry. If possible, it's always a good idea to bend the ear of someone with first-hand experience in the sort of role or career you're aiming for, and ask them nuanced questions like this.

I think you don't have any choice and shouldn't waste time thinking about what potential employers will think: you apply with the CV you have, not someone else's. Not getting a recommendation from a person you worked closely with will also hurt.
I think you have the right strategy identified: focus on your specific contributions, and this recommendation will be just one part of your broader application package. Importantly, it'll describe the researcher you are. If applying for a PhD, you can use your other application materials (like a "statement of purpose", if applicable) to be clear about what training steps you're expecting at your next stop. If those goals include getting more familiar with the "hard-nosed" side of your field, that to me shows maturity in an application. On the academic track, you're still early in your development.
I see a lot of people posting on this site with too much "playing the game" in mind as far as (in particular PhD) applications. A lot of the graduate application process is about finding a good fit, so people who play games with their applications may end up admitted somewhere, but they're admitted in a place that is the wrong fit for them: for example, they lied about their research interests and are now finding they can't do the research they actually wanted to do.

Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. Hard not to overanalyze these things, but you're right that it is ultimately a waste of time.

I think you're worrying too much about something that is a minor aspect of this reference.  The reference will ultimately be an evaluation of your own academic skills and contribution relating to your own work on the relevant courses/projects.  As you say, you have already emphasised that your own work is more empirical, etc., and if you get a supporting reference commenting positively on your work and skills then this should read well.
You're also probably misdiagnosing what quantitative/empirical academics think of academics in softer fields.  While there are differences in skills, approaches, and even levels of rigour of analysis, academics in leftist/postmodernist fields are still people who you would expect to have developed good core academic skills (e.g., literature review, research, writing, etc.) who can accurately assess the quality of a prospective PhD candidate.  Your typical postmodernist qualitative academic has strong academic skills (including some skills that are typically more developed than quantitative/empirical academics) and is a perfectly good reference for a budding PhD candidate.
I can't speak for others, but I am a rigorous quantitative guy who does math/stats research and is anti-leftist/postmodernist, but if I got a strong academic reference from an academic who is a leftist/postmodernist type, I would take that as strong evidence of good academic skills for the prospective student (or at least strong potential) and it would carry a lot of (positive) weight with me.

"The jobs I am applying for are in 'hard-nosed' empirical policy fields whereas this professor has a very strong 'leftist/postmodernist' emphasis"
In all hiring situations your chances of getting hired are best if you tailor your "descriptions of your work" to cater to the personal views of those on the hiring committee.
I'm sorry to sound so cynical about this but 99% of the people on hiring committees have NO real experience interviewing people, NOR do they have the "raw cynicism" you might say, to see though baloney.  And EVERY candidate is going to present baloney.  You admitted this yourself when you said you "spin" your descriptions.  Spinning means saying baloney.  Period.
99% of people "go with their gut" so any interview candidate who is skilled can use typical emotional appeal techniques to get a favorable view in most interviews.  You might have trouble getting away with that if the hiring committee consisted of, say, law enforcement officers who are used to people lying to them to their faces - but the average academic is not and will fall for it every time.  In fact, one of the rules of swaying people is that the more the person is convinced they are smarter than you - the easier it is to BS them.  And academics particularly those higher up are notorious in believing they can see through baloney.  The more they believe they can - the easier it is to pull a fast one on them.
So ignore the people telling you to "go with your gut" or other such nonsense and be hard-nosed about this.  When you get an interview setup - get the names of everyone on the hiring committee - read everything you can that they have published to figure out what they are like - and be sharp and get a bead drawn on their personalities during the initial minutes of the interview - and then cater to them.
If you have a committee of conservatives, then spin it like you were the one bringing order and reason to the leftist nonsense they are already going to be biased against - if you have a committee of leftists then spin it like you embraced the modernist philosophy.  Your job here is to get the employment offer - nothing else.  Once you have that in hand THEN you can decide if you will "fit" and enjoy working with them.  But until then - put your feelings and views in a bottle - they are irrelevant.  You are a salesperson at this point - nothing else.  So SELL yourself, dammit!  You WOULDN'T BE THERE if they weren't going to pay you!

"You might have trouble getting away with ['lying to their faces']...", "...the easier it is to BS them", "...the easier it is to pull a fast one on them" This answer might benefit from integrating some of the information from this reference. You appear to be unfamiliar with it.

My psychology is atypical, so (unless someone's particularly good at tailoring to people who think like me) I usually see through things like this. It's one of the few things that prejudices me against a candidate. The behaviour described in this answer is most likely to endear you to the sorts of people who employ such advice, and… do you really want to work in an environment like that?
